# How to reopen and use .xlsx file?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have some conditions as you can see. When I run the codes

```
import tkinter.filedialog

file = filedialog.askopenfilename()

if file:
        try:
            filename = r"{}".format(file)
            df = pd.read_excel(file)
        except ValueError:
            label.config(text="File could not be opened")
        except FileNotFoundError:
            label.config(text="File Not Found")
                         


data = df.loc[df['WELL'] == e2_string ][['DEPTH_MD', 'CALIPER', 'GR', 'LITHOLOGY', 'SHALLOW', 'DEEP']]



e1_float = e1_float * 30/100 + e1_float

df.loc[(df.GR < 30.0000) & (df.CALIPER > e1_float) & (df.SHALLOW > 2.60000)  , "LITHOLOGY"] = '1' 
df.loc[(df.GR > 100.0000) , "LITHOLOGY"] = '3' 
df.LITHOLOGY.fillna('2', inplace=True)



df.to_excel(file)

lithology_numbers = {1: {'lith':'Trona', 'lith_num':1, 'hatch': '+', 'color':'aqua'},
                 2: {'lith':'Shale, Claystone', 'lith_num':2, 'hatch':'-.', 'color':'black'},
                 3: {'lith':'Tuff', 'lith_num':3, 'hatch':'o', 'color':'orange'}}
df_lith = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lithology_numbers, orient='index')
df_lith.index.name = 'LITHOLOGY'

 # Lithology track
    ax4.plot(well["LITHOLOGY"], well['DEPTH_MD'], color = "black", linewidth = 0.5)
    ax4.set_xlabel("Lithology")
    ax4.xaxis.label.set_color("black")
    ax4.set_xlim(0,1)
    ax4.tick_params(axis='x', colors="black")
    ax4.spines["top"].set_edgecolor("black")
    
    
    for key in lithology_numbers.keys():
        color = lithology_numbers[key]['color']
        hatch = lithology_numbers[key]['hatch']
        ax4.fill_betweenx(well['DEPTH_MD'], 0, well['LITHOLOGY'], where=(well['LITHOLOGY']==key),
                         facecolor=color, hatch=hatch)
        

    ax4.set_xticks([0, 1])


    for ax in [ax1, ax2, ax4, ax6]:
        ax.set_ylim(bottom_depth, top_depth)
        ax.grid(which='major', color='lightgrey', linestyle='-')
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position("top")
        ax.xaxis.set_label_position("top")
        ax.spines["top"].set_position(("axes", 1.02))
        
        
    for ax in [ax2, ax3, ax4, ax6]:
        plt.setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), visible = False)
        
    plt.tight_layout()
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace = 0.15)
    
    for key in lithology_numbers.keys():
     color = lithology_numbers[key]['color']
     hatch = lithology_numbers[key]['hatch']
     ax4.fill_betweenx(well['DEPTH_MD'], 0, well['LITHOLOGY'], 
                      where=(well['LITHOLOGY']==key),
                      facecolor=color, hatch=hatch)
```

The lines below these codes do not work as they should. but when I run the same codes again it works as it should. I think the problem stems from not using the final version of the excel file after printing dataframe to excel. So after I print the dataframe to excel, I need to tell it to update that file, but I don't know how to do it. Could you help ?

Comment: I tried to add df = pd.read_excel(file) line to the end. But It didn't work.

Comment: Do the "lines below these codes" use the Excel file?  Why not just use the dataframe?

Comment: Because I couldnt design that, so I checked for alternative solution and I decided to get values after writing.

Comment: Then what comes after those lines?  That's where the problem is, right?

Comment: let me edit the post please

Comment: As you see, Im using LITHOLOGY column in LITHOLOGY track as well(LITHOLOGY). When I use as df(LITHOLOGY), there are many problems in drawing. Thats why I choose using it from excel file.

Comment: Problem is not in the below . I just want python to use excel file just after writing LITHOLOGY column. Instead of doing this, python is using excel file without LITHOLOGY column. But, If I run same codes again, there would be no problem because LITHOLOGY column is already written.

Comment: any solution..?

Comment: You are focusing on the wrong thing here.  There is no point in "filtering" your data through Excel.  The `df` dataframe has the exact same values.  So, figure out why it doesn't work as you have it above.  What gets messed up in the drawing?

Comment: Hi Tim, you can see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71044528/matplotlib-and-dataframe-confusion